# Why cannot I insert 100 rows into table_1 in my PRO*C program?

Tags: c, oracle-pro-c

When I call the post function, I see the s_no in my logs but the insert is not done. I get the "ORA-01722: invalid number".

ORA-01722: invalid number: You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a number, but it was unsuccessful."

```
int post(char (*s_no)[100])
{

  exec sql var s_no is string[100];   

  //sprintf(s_sno) here shows my 100 s_no log. Then I have the s_no whan I call post function  !

  EXEC SQL FOR 100
     insert into table_1(col1)
     select col2
     from table_2
     where col2 = :s_no;
}
```

s_no is a pointer to an array of characters, I don't know how I can convert it.

How can I fix this? !

Thank you !

Comment: You're trying to bind an array of 100 strings to a single number column, 100 times. At best you could loop over your array with a variable and then bind `:s_no[i]`, but have you looked at doing batch inserts? Why do you have your numbers as strings?

Comment: What is the type of table_2:col2?  Is it a string or an integer?

Comment: I am already inside a loop : EXEC SQL FOR 100. I guess each time one of them is assigned. I am not good at all at C and PRO*C but I just guess the problem is with converting in exec sql var s_no is string [100]

Comment: @Dax - then you have a problem, since your types don't match.  You'll have to convert each `s_no[i]` to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to assign a string value to a numeric column; you will need to convert each string to a number value before using it in your SQL statement.

Given its declaration and use in the code, I'm assuming `s_no` corresponds to a 100x100 array of `char` in the calling function, and that each `s_no[i]` contains a *0-terminated string representation* of a numerical value (i.e., `s_no[i] == "123.45"`).  If that's not correct, then we have bigger problems.

So, the first thing you need to do is convert your array of strings to an array of numbers.  Here's one option:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
...
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
double d_no[100];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 100 && s_no[i] != NULL; i++ )
  d_no[i] = strtod( s_no[i], NULL ); 

EXEC SQL FOR 100
  INSERT INTO TABLE_1(COL1)
    SELECT COL2 FROM TABLE_2
    WHERE COL2 = :d_no;
```

Haven't tested this at all, but it should at least give you the flavor of what you need to do.

If any of my assumptions about `s_no` are wrong please let me know and I'll update the code appropriately.

I've seen a number of Pro*C questions using this `s_no` variable in the past few days, and all of them appear to be confusing pointers to strings with numbers; are y'all taking the same class or something?